# How to show/hide a field on dropdown change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I searched Stackoverflow and found lots of answers how I can show/hide a field on dropdown change by jQuery or simple inline js. But my problem is with using it inside a table.

For start let's keep it easy and use inline simple js instead of jQuery. 
I want if recaptcha is chosen then private and public key fields will be visible. I use a table, so the entire row should be hidden. and the rest of form should become upper to be immediately under select menu if those fields should be hidden to avoid gap between rows in table. But it doesn't work for row. and only the second field will be in/invisible because I added the style on field rather than on tr. (just for testing for first one I used it for tr and for second one I used for field to see what happens, but only second one works.) How to set it work for row removal and the rest of form will be upper to avoid two blank rows in form? Answer about how to fix it with jQuery instead of inline simple js is welcome too as my ultimate goal is to go with jQuery.

```
<tr class="something1">
<td class="left">Activate Captcha: </td>
<td class="right"><select name="activate_captcha" onchange="if (this.value=='recaptcha'){this.form['recaptcha'].style.visibility='visible'}else{this.form['recaptcha'].style.visibility='hidden'};">
<option value="none">None</option>
<option value="recaptcha">ReCaptcha</option>
</select>
</td>

</tr>
<tr class="something1" id="recaptcha" style="visibility:hidden;">
<td class="left">ReCaptcha Public Key: </td>
<td class="right"><input type="text" size="40" name="pub_key" value="" /></td>

</tr>
<tr class="something1">
<td class="left">ReCaptcha Private Key: </td>
<td class="right"><input type="text" id="recaptcha" style="visibility:hidden;" size="40" name="priv_key" value="" /></td>
</tr>

</tr>
<tr class="something1">
<td class="left">This row should come up under dropdown if rows above are invisible: </td>
<td class="right"><input type="text" value="" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Where is your attempt to the JS?

Comment: You have multiple elements with `id="recaptcha"`. That's not valid, IDs have to be unique.

Comment: @A.Sharma It's in the `onchange` attribute of `<select name="activate_captcha"`.

Comment: Oh man, I never would have considered putting an entire function's code in an attribute. You should try to modularize your code more. It will be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

IDs need to be unique, so you can't have multiple `id="recaptcha"`. Change them to `class="recaptcha"`.

Then change

```
this.form['recaptcha'].style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

to:

```
recaptcha = this.form.getElementsByClassName('recaptcha');
for (i = 0; i < recaptcha.length; i++) {
    recaptcha[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

In jQuery this becomes:

```
$(this.form).find('.recaptcha').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

The complete code could be:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table>
    <tr class="something1">
      <td class="left">Activate Captcha:</td>
      <td class="right">
        <select name="activate_captcha" onchange="$(this.form).find('.recaptcha').css('visibility', this.value=='recaptcha' ? 'visible' : 'hidden');">
          <option value="none">None</option>
          <option value="recaptcha">ReCaptcha</option>
        </select>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="something1 recaptcha" style="visibility:hidden;">
      <td class="left">ReCaptcha Public Key:</td>
      <td class="right">
        <input type="text" size="40" name="pub_key" value="" />
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="something1">
      <td class="left">ReCaptcha Private Key:</td>
      <td class="right">
        <input type="text" class="recaptcha" style="visibility:hidden;" size="40" name="priv_key" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    </tr>
    <tr class="something1">
      <td class="left">This row should come up under dropdown if rows above are invisible:</td>
      <td class="right">
        <input type="text" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Many thanks. Would you please give the complete jQuery? I appreciate it. @Barmar

Comment: That is the complete jQuery.

Comment: Then the 3rd row will come up under select menu when those 2 fields are hidden?

Comment: For the private key, why do you just hide the input, not the whole row like you do for the public key?

Comment: To your question: sorry, for start I wanted to know which one will be hidden. Now your code works fine except, when hidden the row under private ket is not coming up under select menu to avoid gap in rows. How to fix it?

Comment: another issue, when select menu is recaptcha from start, it should still show the fields, not only on changed. How to fix it?

Comment: I edited the code in your post for private key to get snippet working for second field too. Now two issues remaining as I said in 2 comments above. I appreciate your advice. @Barmar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122791/discussion-between-user4271704-and-barmar).

Comment: @user4271704 To avoid the row gap, you should use `display: none`, not `visibility: hidden'`. You can do this with jQuery `.hide()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone

Comment: To make it show the fields at the start, change the `style=` attribute to match the initial value of the select menu. You can also move the jQuery code into a named function, and call it after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any form with the name `recaptcha` so you can't really use `this.form['recaptcha']`, however, since you have the `id` you can use the `document.getElementById` function to get that specific element, and from there your code is the same.

Check here:

```html
<table>
<tr class="something1">
<td class="left">Activate Captcha: </td>
<td class="right"><select name="activate_captcha" onchange="if (this.value=='recaptcha'){document.getElementById('recaptcha').style.visibility='visible'}else{document.getElementById('recaptcha').style.visibility='hidden'};">
<option value="none">None</option>
<option value="recaptcha">ReCaptcha</option>
</select>
</td>

</tr>
<tr class="something1" id="recaptcha" style="visibility:hidden;">
<td class="left">ReCaptcha Public Key: </td>
<td class="right"><input type="text" size="40" name="pub_key" value="" /></td>

</tr>
<tr class="something1">
<td class="left">ReCaptcha Private Key: </td>
<td class="right"><input type="text" id="recaptcha" style="visibility:hidden;" size="40" name="priv_key" value="" /></td>
</tr>

<tr class="something1">
<td class="left">This row should come up under dropdown if rows above are invisible: </td>
<td class="right"><input type="text" value="" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `this.form['recaptcha']` isn't looking for a form named `recaptcha`, that would be `document.forms['recaptcha']`. `this.form['recaptcha']` is a field named `recaptcha` in the form that contains `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead to add code inline, I prefer to add it at run time.

I changed from visibility to display because you asked to remove blank lines.

My proposal is:

```js
// Polyfill for Internet Explorer 8
if(!("nextElementSibling" in document.documentElement)){
  Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, "nextElementSibling", {
    get: function(){
      var e = this.nextSibling;
      while(e && 1 !== e.nodeType)
        e = e.nextSibling;
      return e;
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('tr.something1 select'), function (element, index) {
    element.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
      if (this.value == 'recaptcha') {
        this.closest('tr').nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
        this.closest('tr').nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
        this.closest('tr').nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        this.closest('tr').nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none';
        this.closest('tr').nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
        this.closest('tr').nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
      }
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="something1">
        <td class="left">Activate Captcha:</td>
        <td class="right"><select name="activate_captcha">
            <option value="none">None</option>
            <option value="recaptcha">ReCaptcha</option>
        </select>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="something1" style="display:none;">
        <td class="left">ReCaptcha Public Key:</td>
        <td class="right"><input type="text" size="40" name="pub_key" value=""/></td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="something1"  style="display:block;">
        <td class="left">ReCaptcha Private Key:</td>
        <td class="right"><input type="text" id="recaptcha" size="40" name="priv_key"
                                 value=""/></td>
    </tr>

    </tr>
    <tr class="something1"  style="display:block;">
        <td class="left">This row should come up under dropdown if rows above are invisible:</td>
        <td class="right"><input type="text" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @user4271704 Could you retry?

Comment: not working, if you run snippet here, it is not working neither here.